# Typescript strict object key names, but allow options for the key name

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, themes, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a strict mapping for a theme, but I want the keys of the mapping, not to be dynamic, but have optional values for the keys. Meaning the key type of "100 | AppBackground" can have one of those keys and the same value. Here are some of the things I have tried. I always want to allow strict key value pairs like `red:color`.

```
type 300 = '300' | 'CardBackground';
export type ThemeMapping = {
  [key: '100' | 'AppBackground']: Color;
  [key in '200' | 'ContentBackground']: Color;
  [key: 300 ]: Color;
  ['400' | 'InactiveBackground']: Color;
  link: Color;
  red: Color;
  yellow: Color;
  green: Color;
  blue: Color;
}
```

I know for dynamic values you can also do `{[key: string]: Color}`. I just want the key type to essentially be options rather than dynamic or just a regular string.

Please let me know if you need me to explain more.

Comment: There is no native way to say "exactly one of these keys" so you'd have to write something yourself.  Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp02pm) what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I believe this is what I want. An explanation would be appreciated. I'm not sure how to access `ExactlyOneProp` or `Pretty`

Comment: @jcalz ahh! Did not see these at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't natively support the concept of "an object with exactly one property from some set", so if you want to emulate it you'll need to write something that works that way yourself.  Here's one approach:

```
type ExactlyOneProp<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: Pick<T, K> & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never }
}[keyof T];
```

The idea is that `ExactlyOneProp<T>` should result in a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with one member for each property of `T`, where each union member should require on key and prohibit the others.  TypeScript also can't exactly *prohibit* a key; instead you can make an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), so the only acceptable thing to do is leave the property out (or maybe set it to `undefined` depending on compiler options).  So `ExactlyOneProp<{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}>` should be equivalent to `{a: 0, b?: never, c?: never} | {a?: never, b: 1, c?: never} | {a?: never, b?: never, c: 2}`.

`ExactlyOneProp<T>` works by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the each property key `K` in `T`, and making a new property of type `Pick<T, K> & {[P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never}` (using [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to be an object with just a known `K` property) and then [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with another mapped type with the keys in `Exclude<keyof T, K>` (using [the `Exclude<X, Y>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to filter out `K` from the keys of `T`) with all optional properties (from the `?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers)) of type `never`.

---

That produces a fairly ugly type, so we will prettify it via

```
type Pretty<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
```

which essentially just collapses all object intersections to their equivalent single-object types (e.g., `{a: 0} & {b: 1}` becomes `{a: 0, b: 1}`.

Let's test that:

```
type Test = Pretty<ExactlyOneProp<{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}>>;
/* type Test = 
   { a: 0; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; } | 
   { b: 1; a?: undefined; c?: undefined; } | 
   { c: 2; a?: undefined; b?: undefined; };
*/
```

Looks good.

---

So now to make `ThemeMapping` the way you'd like, we need to intersect a bunch of different pieces, like this:

```
type ThemeMapping = Pretty<
    ExactlyOneProp<{ 100: Color, AppBackground: Color }> &
    ExactlyOneProp<{ 200: Color, ContentBackground: Color }> &
    ExactlyOneProp<{ 300: Color, CardBackground: Color }> &
    ExactlyOneProp<{ 400: Color, InteractiveBackground: Color }> &
    { link: Color; red: Color; yellow: Color; green: Color; blue: Color }
>;
```

That becomes a union of 2×2×2×2×1 = 16 members, each of which has 2+2+2+2+5 = 13 properties, so displaying it all at once is too much to do here.  It looks like:

```
type ThemeMapping = {
    100: Color; AppBackground?: undefined;
    200: Color; ContentBackground?: undefined;
    300: Color; CardBackground?: undefined;
    400: Color; InteractiveBackground?: undefined;
    link: Color; red: Color; yellow: Color; green: Color; blue: Color;
} | {
    100: Color; AppBackground?: undefined;
    200: Color; ContentBackground?: undefined;
    300: Color; CardBackground?: undefined;
    InteractiveBackground: Color; 400?: undefined;
    link: Color; red: Color; yellow: Color; green: Color; blue: Color;
} | ⋯;
```

You can verify that it behaves as desired by trying out different possibilities:

```
declare const c: Color;
const base = { link: c, red: c, yellow: c, green: c, blue: c };
let t: ThemeMapping;
t = { ...base, "100": c, "200": c, "300": c, "400": c }; // okay
t = { ...base, "100": c, "200": c, "CardBackground": c, "400": c }; // okay
t = { ...base, "100": c, "200": c, "400": c }; // error, missing prop
t = { ...base, "100": c, "200": c, "300": c, 
  "CardBackground": c, "400": c }; // error, extra prop
```

As you wanted, you have to define exactly one of the `300` and `CardBackground` propertes, and you'll get an error if you try to define both or neither.  And you can test the other properties yourself if you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4&filetype=ts#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN7JwBcyAzmFKAObIC+A3MgPRPIDuAFgJ7IBQvYLgAcUAUQAeiMJi4B5EBAAKUdEIA8AFQB8yALz5eyI8gDaAaWShkAawhd0MZBoC6AWgD8JRcATXNAGmQzHQAyfFNFSxBkCQRMAFcAEwg1W3tHDUDg509kBQA3aDpeWhM0hydnen5BEWRlCDBBTR19DWQIcUgQRNIomCKAVWR3cPMomzsKwecSQfNnOmQSAuhqgWEUDQhyPXqoRuaJKRl5JRV1AmJkAAZAgCMSAEZAhBIAJjotLWqmACpkLUtjswHtDEYriQbox7rl4j0IDBQBBEowEHCEUiFKilgAfPjGAiPZBPRhwDHJLEotEUxHInG0ZD48HhN7Id5k2lUnGwkjwyn0xgMXh-Jg1TZODgQAC2EAAsnAhEJqHsGk0uGoWTFJAhpHIFMpVGoCE8bjcSBhsFBAgBBJUAIUQ1ioKn5FqwOC+yBCWuOutOBouxvZZvdVsCGHAEHAjt8LvQbrQHtwtFCvp1erOhsuyAAzKGk+G0HAoIlY87XT0w57U970yd9ecjQQACwFy04QIASSjUCkwEK5fjiY7KbTxnCmFA1mrUEYB0Ss8YXAgmGwbCXyBdEGjm-uCQgs+KP14yTiJZQCHQIF2bNHvCvN9B9zgpBQ+gIU5AM+QCECC5IP9kBXNd0A3X9Am3XcIOQfd4kPX86GqTBGkBEgNClWUFSVahqlBD9kAAOmIl830CAAiU0bnIwCKPeM0aJg8j82o2jkHIttWMQhhmFYdBrDgLgBD2AhiMI0iIAoqjGKA8j6K42TUBLMsnWHHoZIoziZKQ3jkH4wThIIsSJKkhi2LksymK0wCdJYDooBUa1kGlYBSFIFUhAuQzwmM19JPY6TzPkjT2JYkLyKU0sh0rRJwus7jGDs6BHMCToKDgZBPNUfh-kBCUMJleVFWVEAaA-LUqKXLU7SEaKEx6LlBS1eSqonSNujAOr+Ua7FqgnFjWuMSKVLjGKeupLVOMGowe0gPtdQHCAuoavlMSaicvx-Uc+uMADCxwHajBA9dpq3A5oO2rU4IQy7GXxPAKvbZNDuQGrlsScbUWap6rRe9ro061SxtWgVeq1Ab9rnLVhvez6Xtm6B+0HIH6sXSGXs4uGtU2069suidjrA06oJAU7rqqu6DAnSr0eqh0Ue6kG6TBicWtptrrw62Gme5P7lPe06WKxicpvZ4wEfmsBFu55B+WZiaNunXGUVOwnwPx4wSbJg8KaZKnjBpjWjDehmVtltaWeMNmjaTKMY1Nj6efWob+YdwWzWF8XeyRpa3bFoxMady2jBx-3kDx56tTV4nztJsPydpymHupn6Drp2qHc9ox-vt0bUdO+Ss7zVOoba1288Z83QYV4xRZtiWfZluXeexpWw4j36o9XE6w61+OdcTvXk4NkuXpNiuzeb53s85gGBbDwug5rowIZtmGHaI4iCWQUV+D3-eD8Pg+gA)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the `error, extra prop` is happening because the value of the key `CardBackground` is a string and not the `c` type

Comment: That was a typo, it’s still an error as desired

Answer (score 1):

First, you can define the types for each group and a base theme mapping type with fixed properties, like this:

```js
type Color = string; // Replace this with your actual Color type

type Key100 = '100' | 'AppBackground';
type Key200 = '200' | 'ContentBackground';
type Key300 = '300' | 'CardBackground';
type Key400 = '400' | 'InactiveBackground';

type ThemeMappingBase = {
  link: Color;
  red: Color;
  yellow: Color;
  green: Color;
  blue: Color;
};
```

Next, create your mapped types:

```js
type ThemeMapping100 = { [key in Key100]: Color };
type ThemeMapping200 = { [key in Key200]: Color };
type ThemeMapping300 = { [key in Key300]: Color };
type ThemeMapping400 = { [key in Key400]: Color };
```

Finally, combine the base theme with the partial mapped types:

```js
export type ThemeMapping = ThemeMappingBase &
  Partial<ThemeMapping100> &
  Partial<ThemeMapping200> &
  Partial<ThemeMapping300> &
  Partial<ThemeMapping400>;
```

[image: code provided]

I'm not really sure if this meets your needs, but hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple types to achieve this behavior.

```js
type MyFirstType = "100" | "AppBackground"

type MySecondType = "200" | "ContentBackground"

type CombinedType = MyFirstType | MySecondType | "red" | "link"

type ThemeMapping = Record<CombinedType, Color>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Not exactly what I want. I knew this was possible. I don't want all the keys the have the same possible values. key1 can be x values and key 2 can be x values, etc.